# if $m\mid p-1$ then there are exactly $m$ elements $a \bmod p$ for which $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that if $m\mid p-1$ then there are exactly $m$ elements $a \bmod p$ for which $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

What I have tried/done:

One way is to argue that the polynomial $a^m-1$ has exactly $m$ roots. I am looking for a different proof. I want something more "instructive"/computational/direct proof.(If that makes any sense.)

I also do not want to rely on the result that if $m|p-1$, then there are exactly $\phi(m)$ elements of order $m$, nor do I want to rely on any more general group theory result. I would like to see a proof using elementary number theory only.

Comment: Do you about generators modulo $p?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I appreciate the comment. Yes I do. I want use this result to prove the exitance of generators. "I also do not want to rely on the result that if m|p−1, then there are exactly ϕ(m) elements of order m." And this implies the exsitance of a generator

Comment: You'll need to use the fact that $\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$ is a field (else the claim is not true).  But then the claim is generally true for any  finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field.  See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic) for a discussion.

Comment: @Cram This is true not just for primes but in general for any $n$ which has a primitive root i.e. $n = 2, 4$ or  $n = p, p^a, 2p^a$ for an odd prime $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb F_p=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z.$ Let $f:\mathbb F_p^{\times}\to \mathbb F_{p}^\times$ be defined as $f(x)=x^{(p-1)/m}.$

For any $x\in \mathbb F_p^\times,$ $f(x)^m =x^{p-1}= 1.$ So all the elements of $S=\{f(x)\mid x\in\mathbb F_p\}$ are solutions to $x^m-1.$

Now, if $a\in S,$ then $f^{-1}(a)$ is the set of roots of $x^{(p-1)/m}-a,$ so $\left|f^{-1}(a)\right|\leq \frac{p-1}m.$

So:

$$p-1=|\mathbb F_p^{\times}|=|f^{-1}(S)|=\sum_{a\in S} |f^{-1}(a)|\leq \sum_{a\in S}\frac{p-1}m=|S|\cdot\frac{p-1}{m}.$$

So $|S|\geq m.$

But $S$ is a set of (possibly not all) roots of a polynomial $x^m-1$ of degree $m,$ so we also get $|S|\leq m.$

---

This gives you a computational way of computing the set of roots of $x^m-1,$ albeit not much more efficient than just checking them. It really depends on whether $m>\frac{p-1}m$ whether it might be more efficient.

---

So we've used:

> 1. $\mathbb F_p$ is a field of size $p.$
> 2. A polynomial of degree $d$ over a field has at most $d$ roots.
> 3. $x^{p-1}=1$ for each $x\in\mathbb F_p^{\times}.$

1. is used just to use 2.
2. is used to show $x^{(p-1)/m}-a$ and $x^m-1$ have at most $\frac{p-1}m$ and $m$ roots in $\mathbb F_p,$ respectively.
3. Is used to show that the elements of $S$ are roots of $x^m-1.$